# what command to use to start chrome with extensions on?

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I am starting the chrome browser in app mode using

```
$ google-chrome-stable --app="http://example.com"
```

in order to start the browser without the tab bar and other UI elements. However in order to turn on an extension I need to open a new chrome windows (thus revealing the normal UI components) and manually turning on the extension. The keyboard shortcut for extensions also don't work in app mode, so that doesn't work.

Is there a terminal command I can use to make sure all, or some, extensions are on when the browser launches? Or even a setting within chrome that I haven't found yet? Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable all the extensions in settings and make them available on Incognito mode?

Comment: Yes, the extension is working fine. It's just that I have to manually turn it on every time the browser launches.

Comment: Also, using the keyboard shortcut that I set in the settings doesn't work when in app mode.

Comment: It's beyond my knowledge. Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

i don't know which version of chrome you are using so , 
the terminal command is

```
--enable-apps
```

or

```
--enable-extension-apps
```

use it the same way you use the other commands to start chrome.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Upon using the commands you provided I am still unable to make it work. I am currently trying to open duolingo.com in app mode, and I need the "Phonetic Lookup" extension to be on in order to better study the phonetics of my vocabulary. Using the --enable-extension-apps doesn't really enable the extension (or the keyboard shortcut) for me.

Comment: pfff, too bad. thats the one and only command for chrome to start with enabled apps. usually chrome starts with apps enabled by default.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with apps enabled. I am using the command line to start chrome in app mode, and I don't really need to use chrome apps.

Comment: sorry , im used to android development and i sometimes use "apps" word. **extensions enabled. Chrome has them enabled by default and saves the last state to reopen with disabled the ones we disabled. Anyway... chrome only has that command for the extensions, too bad it didn't help.